# javascript while adding values it calculates like string

Tags: javascript

adding subtotal+vat+cst+round to grand total

```
function update_totals()
    {
    var grand_total = 0;
    var grand_subtotal = 0;
        var vat=0;
        var cst=0;
       var rounds =  parseInt($('.round').val());


    var vat_percent =  parseInt($('.vat-percent').val());
    if ( (vat_percent < 0) || (vat_percent > 90) ) { vat_percent=10; $('.vat-percent').find('input').val(10); }

    var cst_percent = parseInt($('.cst-percent').val());
    if ( (cst_percent < 0) || (cst_percent > 90) ) { cst_percent=10; $('.cst-percent').find('input').val(10); }

        $('#invoice-items .cell').children('.subtotal-cell').each(function(){

        grand_subtotal += parseFloat( $(this).find('input').val() );
    });



        vat=(grand_subtotal * (vat_percent/100)).toFixed(2);
        cst=(grand_subtotal * (cst_percent/100)).toFixed(2);
       grand_total = (grand_subtotal + vat + cst rounds);
    grand_subtotal = grand_subtotal.toFixed(2);

        grand_total =(grand_subtotal) + (vat);
    //update dom
    $('.sub-total').val(grand_subtotal);
    $('.vat').val(vat);
        $('.cst').val(cst);
        $('.grand-total').val(grand_total);

    }
```

look for error in picture  two values and adding side by side
adding to grand_total =grand_subtotal + vat + cst + round 
it shows  25.001.25   in this 25.00 is subtotal 1.25 is vat

thanks

Comment: `toFixed()` returns a string, so change those lines and just use `toFixed()` right before outputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Returns) returns a string.

As a side note: Given that `0.1 * 0.2` in JavaScript comes out at `0.020000000000000004` do you really want to be doing financial calculations using floating point arithmetic?

[How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure here but are you missing `+`.

```
grand_total = (grand_subtotal + vat + cst rounds);
```

I mean it should be

```
grand_total = (grand_subtotal + vat + cst + rounds);
```

Just a small input.

Comment: If that was the actual issue, the code would not even be executed. It also doesn't solve the OP's problem.